# Major iOS 5 features that cannot be used in iOS 4

Tags: ios5, ios4

### Update - Example

The UIScrollView property in UIWebView is available for iOS 5 or later. I find this out by searching Apple's developer site for all of my UI element class one by one.

Things like this, is there a full collection for iOS 5 features?

### Original Post

Such as which method of UIView is only available in iOS 5 or later.

I can't find out the problem why my app can't run on iOS 4.3 device but runs on iOS 5 or later.

Thank you!

If there are many new features iOS 5, how can I find it all in one place instead of reading Apple's website page by page?

Comment: Still supporting iOS 4.3? Your life must be tough.

Comment: Hi @yoeriboven, Not supporting iOS 4.3 any more, just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found [it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1). Apple made a good summary.